# Why does the split(string, regex) in awk use the last field in first position?

Tags: bash, awk

quick awkscript as follows:

```
awk ' BEGIN{
split("A\nB\nC\nD", fooarray)
i=0
for (i in fooarray) print fooarray[i] 
} '
```

Output:

```
D
A
B
C
```

I feel like im missing out on some major detail, but how is D no in last position? As in

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: awk makes no guarantee about the order you will traverse an array when using `in` you can manually walk the array if you want to ensure an order (or set some `PROCINFO` something in awk 4+ I believe).

Comment: Follow this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array) and pay attention in the last paragraph of 8.1.5

Comment: Interestingly, for me `gawk` gives `A B C D` and `nawk` gives `B C D A`.

Comment: @Vytenis My `gawk` gives `D A B C` The `in` gives random output, that is why you see variation.  This is from the `awk` manual `The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array elements within awk and cannot be controlled or changed. This can lead to problems if new elements are added to array by statements in the loop body; it is not predictable whether or not the for loop will reach them. Similarly, changing var inside the loop may produce strange results. It is best to avoid such things.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D IS in the last position, you're just not accessing the array in consecutive numerical order of its indices. Look:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
split("A\nB\nC\nD", fooarray)
for (i in fooarray) print fooarray[i]
print "-------"
for (i=1; i in fooarray; i++) print fooarray[i]
}'
D
A
B
C
-------
A
B
C
D
```

I feel like this topic causes a lot of confusion so let's see if I can clarify it:

2 fundamental qualities of awk arrays are:

1. ALL array indices are strings, even the ones that look numerical, and
2. arrays are stored as hash tables for efficiency.

So imagine you have a string like `"A B C"` that you want to invoke `split()` on to store in an array. When you do `split("A B C", arr)` you get something like this in memory:

```
 arr[  "3:C"   "1:A"    "2:B"   ]
```

i.e. the values A, B and C are hashed to some memory locations and stored there along with the value of an index that indicates the order they appeared in the original string. The hashing algorithm can put them in memory in any order. Google "hash tables". So the array is really stored as this hash table:

```
arr content @ address 1 = "index=3, value=C"
arr content @ address 2 = "index=1, value=A"
arr content @ address 3 = "index=2, value=B"
```

The `in` operator for efficiency (otherwise why bother with hash tables) simply accesses the elements of an array in the order they are stored in memory, so when you do

```
for (i in arr)
```

you get the contents of `arr` accessed in the order they are stored in the hash table:

```
address=1 => i = 3, arr[i] = C
++address => i = 1, arr[i] = A
++address => i = 2, arr[i] = B
```

with `i` being set to 3 then 1 then 2 and so arr[i] having the values C then A then B. Note the simple, efficient arithmetic `++address` to traverse the contents of `arr`.

If on the other hand you write:

```
for (i=1; i in arr; i++)
```

then awk sets `i` to `1` and then has to do a hash lookup of the array to search for the element that has the index `1` and print that so you get:

```
i=1
search arr for address containing index i=1
=> address = 2, i = 1, arr[1] = A
++i
search arr for address containing index i=2
=> address = 3, i = 2, arr[2] = B
++i
search arr for address containing index i=3
=> address = 1, i = 3, arr[3] = C
```

See the difference in efficiency? Now we're no longer simply traversing memory addresses incrementally, we're doing a hash lookup for every desired index.

When you write `i in arr` in a conditional context, e.g. `if (i in arr)` or `for (i=1; i in arr; i++)` instead of a looping range context `for (i in arr)` then all you are asking awk to do is a hash lookup of `i` to see if it exists in the array:

```
search arr for address containing index i
return 1 if found, 0 otherwise.
```

If you had an array that you populated manually with string indices like:

```
arr["First"] = "Bill"
arr["Last"]  = "Smith"
arr["Title"] = "Mr."
```

and lets pretend the hashing algorithm creates array contents based on the length of their values then you'd get:

```
arr[   "Title:Mr."   "First:Bill"    "Last:Smith"    ]
```

and everything described above would work exactly the same way, so the fact that the first example used numerical-looking indices 1, 2, and 3, is completely irrelevant to the way in which arrays in awk work - all indices are strings and the array contents are stored as a hash table of `index + value` pairs.

In GNU awk you can change the behavior of the `in` operator to look up array contents based on various criteria instead of simply walking the addresses in order by populating `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` - you can set this for example to specific predefined strings to tell `in` to lookup the array contents based on numerical or string order of indices, ascending or descending, or various other criteria and you can write your own functions to control the order. This is immensely useful to improve the brevity of your code IF you need a specific order of array traversal but obviously comes with a performance penalty if you use it and don't need it. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal for details.

Hopefully that helps explain the way awk array storage and the `in` operator work. If not - sorry for adding to the confusion!

Comment: I have never seen this before: `(i=1; i in fooarray; i++)`. Nice to know that there is way to get it back in correct order without use of some type of sort.  But if I use this `print (i in fooarray)` or `print i in fooarray` it gives `1`, so not sure how it works.

Comment: Before I saw this, I would have used `n=split("A\nB\nC\nD", fooarray)` and `for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print fooarray[i]`

Comment: Thank you, i've never seen this for-loop before. Still have to wrap my head around how i is set to the last index of the array (4) at the beginning of the loop and then suddenly jumps back to 1...

Comment: @Jotne the array has no guaranteed order in memory as it is simply a hash. The indices of the array are ALWAYS in the order 1->4 in the order of the values in the string passed to split(). For efficiency the `in` operator by default accesses the array in the order it's stored in memory, not the order of the indices. When you do `print i in array` you are printing the result of testing whether or not the value stored in variable `i` is an index in the array so you get `1` or `0` output. The loop just sets i to 1 and increments it until i has a value that is not an index in the array.

Comment: Mustermann The first loop loops through all of the indices of the array in the order the hash is stored in memory. The second loop sets i to 1 and increments i until it has a value that is not an index of the array. No jumping involved.

Comment: @Jotne & Mustermann - I added some info to my answer to clarify the way in which awk arrays and the `in` operator work. Hope it helps.

Comment: @EdMorton It should be possible to give a post more than one vote.  I do learn allot from you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

awk makes no guarantee about the order you will traverse an array when using `in`.

You can manually walk the array (numerically using the return value from `split)` if you want to ensure an order.

Or, for versions of awk 4+ (I believe) you can set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to an appropriate value. See the [GNU Awk User’s Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal) for details.