# Associative arrays for grandmothers using awk

Tags: awk, associative-array

I have a really hard time wrapping my head around arrays and associative arrays in awk. 
Say you want to compare two different columns in two different files using associative arrays, how would you do? Let's say column 1 in file 1 with column 2 in file two, then print the the matching, corresponding values of file 1 in a new column in file 2. Please explain each step really simply, as if talking to your grandmother, I mean, super-thoroughly and super-simple.
Cheers

Comment: Did you have any particular programming language in mind ?

Comment: ah, yes, I was thinking awk

Comment: Perhaps an `awk` tag might be a good idea then ?

Comment: "I'll do it for you, Granny" :-)

Comment: try `http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-22`

Comment: Honestly, I don't quite understand this.
But could anyone just tell me what this means?
a[$1]=$2
"We could use the first field of the input line as the index to the second field with the following assignment"
What does it practically do? I'm creating an array named "a" containing the values of column 1? And then I'm comparing that to column 2? And then storing the matches in "a"?

Comment: @tnocs  The strings in column 1 are being used as the keys in the array.  The strings in column 2 are the values being stored in the array. The keys of the array are similar to the indexes, but they are not integers.  Because the array is not ordered linearly; rather it is an associative array, and the keys are arbitrary strings.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the keys does, how does the strings of column 1 influence the array?

Comment: @tnocs `=` is the awk ASSIGNMENT operator, the COMPARISON operator is `==`. `x=3` means `set the variable x to the value 3`. `x=$2` means `set the variable x to the value of 2nd input field`. `a[$1]=$2` means `set the memory location indicated by array a indexed by the value of the 1st field to the value of the 2nd field`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grandma - let's say you want to make jam out of strawberries, raspberries, and blueberries, one jar of each.

You have a shelf on your wall with room/openings for 3 jars on it. That shelf is an associative array: `shelf[]`

Stick a label named "strawberry" beneath any one of the 3 openings. That is the index of an associative array: `shelf["strawberry"]`

Now place a jar of strawberry jam in the opening above that label. That is the contents of the associative array indexed by the word "strawberry": `shelf["strawberry"] = "the jar of strawberry jam"`

Repeat for raspberry and blueberry.

When you feel like making yourself a delicious sandwich, go to your shelf (array), look for the label (index) named "strawberry" and pick up the jar sitting above it (contents/value), open and apply liberally to bread (preferably Mothers Pride end slices).

Now - if a wolf comes to the door, do not open it in case he steals your sandwich or worse!

Comment: If you'd like something a bit more technical with a smidgen more detail about awk associative arrays, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159886/why-does-the-splitstring-regex-in-awk-use-the-last-field-in-first-position/27160057#27160057

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation of associative arrays (aka maps), not specifically for awk:

Unlike a normal array, where each element has a numeric index, an associative array uses a "key" instead of an index. You can think of it as being like a simple flat-file database, where each record has a key and a value. So if you have, e.g. some salary data:

```
Fred    10000
John    12000
Sara    11000
```

you could store it in an associative array, `a`, like this:

```
a["Fred"] = 10000
a["John"] = 12000
a["Sara"] = 11000
```

and then when you wanted to retrieve a salary for a person you would just look it up using their name as the key, e.g.

```
salary = a[person]
```

You can of course modify the values too, so if you wanted to give Fred a 10% pay rise you could do it like this:

```
a["Fred"] = a["Fred"] * 1.1
```

And if you wanted to set Sara's salary to be the same as John's you could write:

```
a["Sara"] = a["John"]
```

So an associative array is just an array that maps keys to values. Note that the keys do not need to be strings, and the values do not need to be numeric, but the basic concept is the same regardless of the data types. Note also that one obvious constraint is that keys need to be unique.